# According to Catholicism, why did Jesus address inanimate objects?

Tags: catholicism, exegesis, gospel-of-mark, words-of-jesus

In [Mark 4:35–39 (RSVCE)](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=mark+4%3A35-39&version=RSVCE), we read:

> On that day, when evening had come, he said to them, “Let us go across to the other side.”  And leaving the crowd, they took him with them, just as he was, in the boat. And other boats were with him.  And a great storm of wind arose, and the waves beat into the boat, so that the boat was already filling.  But he was in the stern, asleep on the cushion; and they woke him and said to him, “Teacher, do you not care if we perish?”  And he awoke and rebuked the wind, and said to the sea, “Peace! Be still!” And the wind ceased, and there was a great calm.

One wonders why Jesus spoke to inanimate objects like the wind and the sea. Did Mark want to tell his readers that natural forces also have the power of perception and cognition? What does the Catholic Church teach on this topic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

He wanted to show His control over the universe. See St. Thomas Aquinas's discussion on God's divine governance in his [*Summa Theologica* (I q. 103)](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/FP/FP103.html#FPQ103OUTP1).

[St. Bede says this](http://file:///home/alan/Documents/Res%20pro%20Deo/Aquinas/Bilingual/CAMark.htm#4) about the mystical sense:

> Rising up, He threatened the wind, because when He had triumphed in His resurrection, He prostrated the pride of the devil. He ordered the sea to be still, that is, in rising again, He cast down the rage of the Jews. The disciples are blamed, because after His resurrection, He chided them for their unbelief. And we also when being marked with the sign of the Lord's cross, we determine to quit the world, embark in the ship with Christ; we attempt to cross the sea; but, He goes to sleep, as we are sailing amidst the roaring of the waters, when amidst the strivings of our virtues, or amidst the attacks of evil spirits, of wicked men, or of our own thoughts, the flame of our love grows cold. Amongst storms of this sort, let us diligently strive to awake Him; He will soon restrain the tempest, pour down peace upon us, give us the harbour of salvation.